# PreviousPage = null in crosspage posting

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to pass post data from one page to the next but PreviousPage always equals null.

This is what I have in the original page (inside an updatepanel
)

```
<asp:Button ID="mmGo" runat="server" Text="Merge" PostBackUrl="~/Default2.aspx?action=merge"/>
```

Then in the following page I have:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Default.aspx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

...and in the .cs file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PreviousPage != null)
    {
        string action = Request.QueryString["action"];
        if (action == "merge")
        {
            UpdatePanel SourceControl = (UpdatePanel)PreviousPage.FindControl("UpdatePanel1");
            HiddenField SourceTextBox = (HiddenField)SourceControl.FindControl("txtListIDs");
            if (SourceTextBox != null)
            {
                Label1.Text = SourceTextBox.Value;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "page is not cross page post back!";
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the PreviousPage is always equal to null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`PreviousPage` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) returns the page that sent control to this page using `Server.Transfer`.

> If the current page is being rendered as a result of a direct request (not a transfer or cross-post from another page), the PreviousPage property contains null.

Comment: So using the PostBackURL attribute on the button is not a transfer or cross-post?

Comment: Correct.  That creates a normal postback to a different page.

Comment: How do I create a cross-post from another page then?

Comment: Request.Form dosn't send any form data.
"To use cross-page posting, you simply set PostBackUrl to the name of another
web form. When the user clicks the button, the page will be posted to that new URL with the values from
all the input controls on the current page." - Pro asp.NET in CSharp 4th Edition.

I'm a little confused here!

Comment: @baked: And `Request.Form` will have all of the input values.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was the button was inside an update panel but had no postback trigger set.

Answer (score 2):

Yes... It's working... when you use button or linkbutton, use postbackurl, Don't use response.redirect. When you use postbackurl property you can have control, to control the previou page... for reference watch this video,,

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1AqBtOYOMI

Difference between postbackurl and Response.Redirect ?

PostBackURL sends all the form data to the assigned page. Whereas when using Response.Redirect your sending the form data to your current page then moving your user to the assigned page